# Slide in HTML5 video from left and play / pause on slide out?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, video

I have this fiddle where on the click of a button an iframe slides in from the left and plays then when it slides back out it stops.

I'm a bit lost as to how I would apply this in HTML5 video terms. (Basically HTML5 video instead of an iframe) I want the video to slide in on click and play then pause on click and slide out.

http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/8ZFMJ/60/

Any help would be appreciated or if someone could point me in the right direction of how to achieve this.

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">

    <div class="content-wrapper">

        <a href="#" id="play-video">Play Video</a>

           <div class="padLeft">
               <p>Paragraph Goes Here</p>
                 <h3>Play Video</h3>
           </div>

   </div>    

    <div class="full-video">

        <iframe id="video" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/vIu85WQTPRc" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

    </div>  

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.content-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    background: red;
    bottom: -90px;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: bottom 1s;
    -moz-transition: bottom 1s;
    transition: bottom 1s;    
}

#play-video {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: blue;
    z-index: 999;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.full-video {
    position: absolute;
    left: -600px;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: left 1s;
    -moz-transition: left 1s;
    transition: left 1s;  
}

.full-video iframe {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%; 
}
```

**JS**

```
var clicked=false;
var src=$("#video")[0].src;
$("#play-video").on('click', function(){
    if(clicked)
    {
        clicked=false;
        $(".full-video").css({"left": "-600px"});
        $("#video")[0].src = src;
        ev.preventDefault();
    }
    else
    {
        clicked=true;
        $(".full-video").css({"left": "0"});
        $("#video")[0].src = src+"?autoplay=1";
        ev.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: I need to apply this sort of thing to HTML5 <video>, any idea how to do it?

Comment: replace the <iframe> with your video element and when the user clicks to slide in/out trigger the .play() or .pause method on the video ID

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response, would you mind demonstrating that in my code for me? Many thanks. It doesn't have to work I just want to be accurate about how I write the js.